# Angular ngFor not iterating

Tags: angular

This is my template

```html
<div *ngIf="attachments">
    <div>
        {{ 'attachments' | translate }}
    </div>
    {{ attachments.data[0].title }} <!-- this works -->
    <div *ngFor="let item of attachments.data"> <!-- this doesn't -->
        <a [href]="item.href">{{ item.title }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when i print title above like this `attachments.data[0].title` it shows, but when i try to iterate over `attachments.data` it doesn't show

Sorry i didn't write it. It does not show any error it just does not render

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: Would be great if you could provide more data as we currently see there is no error we can't give you an answer to that

Comment: Can you please print the output of attachments.data here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the current limited information, there is only one reason it wouldn't work, and that's because it's an `Object` with numerical string keys and not an `Array`.

Something like this:

```
this.attachments = {
  data: {
   0: { title: 'hi' },
   1: { title: 'bye' }
  }
};
```

You can try to reassign your `attachments.data` variable where you obtain it:

```
this.attachments.data = Object.values(this.attachments.data);
```

Comment: And true that was the case, i am sorry i didn't respond sooner i was trying to figure out what was wrong